# Custom domain is not forwarding to Github page

Tags: github, dns, github-pages, cname

I already tried the three step process:

1) Created a CNAME file in my github repo with the domain name, mydomain.com;

2) Redirected the A Record to 192.30.252.153
and 192.30.252.154

3) CNAME Alias has host "www" pointing to "username.github.io"

But for some reason my mydomain.com is still just the default landing page for new domains and when I go to username.github.io, it just goes to mydomain.com with the same default landing page. Can someone please help? I am registered with domain.com

Additionally, there is a warning message on my Github settings stating,

> Domain does not resolve to the GitHub Pages server. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: How long have you waited? DNS changes take some time to propagate.

Comment: Who is hosting your DNS zone? Could you put the domain name in a comment?